# @Produces for the current user object in JSF2 and JAX-RS?

Tags: jsf-2, jax-rs, cdi, resteasy

I've a simple `@Stateless` EJB that looks like this (stripped of all logging and error handling):

```
@Stateless
public class CurrentUserBean {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Produces @Named @LoggedIn
    @SessionScoped
    public User produceCurrentUser() {
        Principal principal = Faces.getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal();
        String username = (principal == null ? null : principal.getName());

        return em.createNamedQuery("findByLogin", User.class)
                .setParameter("login", username)
                .getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

Works fine when the user logs in with JSF. But the same user can also authenticate via webservice, where I can (need to?) get the user principal from `SecurityContext` in a bean controlled by JAX-RS (resteasy in my case):

```
public User doAuth(@Context SecurityContext ctx) {
    return em.createNamedQuery("findByLogin", User.class)
         .setParameter("login", ctx.getUserPrincial().getName())
         .getSingleResult();
}
```

How can I unify these approaches so that the production of the current user object is the responsibility of only one class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CDI allows you to inject the `Principal` directly.  Just do this:

`@Inject Principal userPrincipal;`

And that will have the user name.

Comment: That works, if they're authenticating via REST. If they're using JSF it wouldn't surprise me that it would blow up. I'm actually not sure on the best course of action here.

Comment: What do you mean?  If you authenticate via JSF, I'm assuming you're calling `request.login(username,password)` to populate the `Principal`.

Comment: The OP stats that "the same user can also authenticate via webservice, where I can (need to?) get the user principal from SecurityContext in a bean controlled by JAX-RS". They're looking for a way to handle both.

Comment: I've verified that the producer method has a proper `Principal` injected when used with JSF. Very cool trick.